# Magento 2: Add specification tab to product page

Tags: tabs, magento2.2.6, product-tab

At Magento 2 I had create attribute sets for every category.

- In attribute set I had a folder with some attributes (visible on
  frontend)
- I need to add all this attributes to a tab with name specifications.
- All these attributes are visible in comparison

  How can I do this? Is any extension for that?

Answer (score -1):

Solved - M2 Product Tabs swissuplabs

https://swissuplabs.com/product-tabs-magento-2-extension.html